# Change hostname after running a container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker, i am using docker version 1.12. I am trying to modify the hostname of a running container, however the **hostname** command returns **hostname: you must be root to change the host name** . Is there any way to achieve that after running the container and not in the docker run command?

Comment: Why do you need to modify the hostname of a running container?

Comment: I am actually trying to reproduce what the -h option does in an intermediate container -created and removed in the RUN instruction of a Dockerfile- during an image build, it happens that i can't change the hostname after the container is created, i tried to edit the /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname files in ssh, still the hostname command returns the container id.

Comment: I mean is this a learning exercise and you're trying to understand how it works, or do you need it to solve a specific problem. If it's a specific problem, there might be a different approach you can take (like injecting environment variables). If it's a learning exercise then it's an interesting question.

Comment: I would say both. Well, you say i could inject environment variables, and in that way all the intermediate containers will take these values, like i could do ENV hostname = FQDN, and all the created containers will return the FQDN for the hostname command ? For the exercise aspect, i'm wandering if the -h option does more than editing the /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname files ?

Comment: I agree with @Roman here if there is a need apart from learning then probably take the custom environment variable route something like
in docker-compose
```
service:
  ...
  ...
  X-HOST: <hostname>
  ...
```
and use this in your work inside the container.

Answer (score 5):

Some discussions here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8902

What I got from above discussion is

1. add `SYS_ADMIN` cap when run the container:
   https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8902#issuecomment-218911749
2. use `nsenter`
   https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8902#issuecomment-241129543

Comment: Hi, so one must run the container with the SYS_ADMIN  option in the first place

Comment: Hi @saadoune, according to the discussion mentioned in this answer, if you don't want to use "SYS_ADMIN", you can also try "docker run -h somehostname" to start a container.

Answer (score 2):

By following Below Steps you can set after start/run the container.

1.Stop container and service

sudo docker stop CONTAINER_NAME

sudo service docker stop

2.Edit config file (JSON) [You should always make backup first]

/var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/config.json

Replace

```
"Hostname":"WHATEVER"
```

with

```
"Hostname":"NEW_HOSTNAME"
```

3.Start container and service

sudo service docker start

sudo docker start CONTAINER_NAME